# Examples of how to apply algebraic number theory

Tags: soft-question, algebraic-number-theory

I am reading about algebraic number theory mainly following milne's notes. 
But currently I really wonder how such theory can help solve problems of number theory. One example I know is we can use Gauss integer to determine when a prime is equal to the sum of two squares. Another example is use Minkowski theorem to prove four squares theorem.

So I would like to know more examples, which illustrate how algebraic number theory can be used to solve problems like the two examples above. I guess I ask this question just because I need more motivation. Thanks!

Comment: The Ramanujan-Nagell theorem is a very good example, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Historically, algebraic number theory was developed to help solve diophantine equations, and of course is still an indispensable tool in doing so.

For those with a preference for "real world" applications, the fastest known method for factoring large integers is the number field sieve, which relies heavily on algebraic number theory.

Comment: Thanks! Especially do you know any text that has more material about how to apply the theory? I do look over through several text but can not find too much examples and application.

Comment: If you want applications specifically, you could look at Henri Cohen's book A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I like.

Fix a prime $p$ ,and $d$ dividing $p-1$. Then there is a monic polynomial $f(x) \in Z[x]$ of degree $d$ such that:

Apart from finitely many primes $q$, $q$ is a $d$th power mod $p$ iff $f(x)$ mod $q$ has root iff $f(x)$ mod $q$ splits to distinct linear roots.

Comment: Polynomials and their roots mod primes are attackable: every monic polynomial $f(x) \in Z[x]$ splits into distinct linear factors mod infinitely many primes.